# how to add new row data in current json array angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i have added new row but i want update new row data also in database but there is no updated data how to get new row data also add address json array

```
     <tr  ng-repeat="x in Profile.addresses">
       <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.site_name ' name='site_name'></td>
       <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.street_address ' name='street_address'></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.city ' name='city'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.state ' name='state'></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.country ' name='country'></td>
```

```
    <tr ng-repeat="lines in array">

 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.site_name ' name='site_name'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.street_address ' name='street_address'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.city ' name='city'></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.state ' name='state'></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.country ' name='country'></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.zip_code ' name='zip_code'></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault"  ng-model='x.phone_number ' name='phone_number'></td>

        </tr>
```

```
    <div class="col-md-2">

<a href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add Address" ng-click="addRow()"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x cust_primary" aria-hidden="true">
```

[image]

Comment: you can use advantage of mvc of angular instead of trying to do dom manipulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, create a counter and an array.

```
$scope.i = 0;
$scope.array = [];
```

Everytime your user clicks on the button, add one to the counter and create the array.

```
$scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.i++;
    $scope.array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.i; i++) {
        $scope.array.push(i);
    }
}
```

In your html, simply repeat the lines based on that counter.

```
<tr ng-repeat="lines in array">
    // Your tds
</tr>
```

**EDIT** Since I can't understand your english, I will give you a generic answer.

Your controller must have an array of objects

```
$scope.i = 0;
$scope.array = [{
    id: 0, 
    address: 'address 1', 
    name: 'Jack Reacher'
}, {
    id: 1, 
    address: 'address 2', 
    name: 'Ethan Hawk'
}];
```

you will then slightly change your addRow function.

```
$scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.i++;
    $scope.array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.i; i++) {
        $scope.array.push({
            id: null, 
            address: '', 
            name: ''
    });
    }
}
```

And in your HTML you use it.

```
<tr ng-repeat="object in array">
    <td>{{object.id}}</td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="object.address" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="object.name" /></td>
</tr>
```

And if you want to save it, you use an `$http` request. I'll let you handle that part.

Comment: how to add these new add row values but current address address array ?

Comment: I'm sorry, can you rephrase ?